# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

so I want to deploy my existing Laravel project into my digital ocean VPS
I used [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/santoshachari/87bf77baeb45a65eb83b553aceb135a3) and I uploaded my site successfully.

My `.env` file is:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=my app key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=my ip
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=form
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=my pass
```

But here is the problem: I used MySQL and created and ran

```
php artisan migrate
```

and got these errors:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = form and table_name = migrations)
```

and

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Comment: Have you defined your database credentials inside `.env` file?

Comment: Take a look here http://laravel.io/forum/09-08-2014-homestead-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Comment: @Froxz seen it already didn't help and his problem was about homestead

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi yes I attached it

Comment: @MohammadReza check your DB / username/ password check if mysql is runing `Connection refused` the error it just can't connect, maybe your user doesn't have enough access and etc.

Comment: Can you connect to mysql manually?

Comment: Can you connect to mysql using your credentials in .env file? `mysql -uroot -pDB_PASSWORD` ?

Comment: @AlexanderKim @ksealey it says `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: @MohammadReza your db is on another server?

Answer (score 38):

In your `.env` file, change `DB_HOST` from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`

Comment: it's not in my localhost beside I attached my .env file

Comment: @Arsalan, Are you using a remote server to store database? Then try domain name instead of IP.

Comment: This solved my problem. But I am unable to understand:

Is there any difference between `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`?

Comment: @GhulamAkbar No difference except if the database is only accepting connections from `localhost`. E.g. in order to accept connections from both, you have to create 2 users, `admin@localhost` and `admin@127.0.0.1`

Comment: I see people mention the opposite, this is not working for me. Migrations work but not when trying to fetch data.

Answer (score 9):

Put string:

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

after DB_PASSWORD=

It works for MAMP. Set your path to mysql.sock

Comment: This worked for me. But I still don't know why it WAS working for so long without problem, and then now at this point it stops working.

Answer (score 6):

In your .env file, change DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to localhost

and then

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan route:clear
3. php artisan config:clear
4. php artisan view:clear

   This worked for me.

Comment: That does not work in Laravel 10

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possibilities why your getting this error.

- database server isn't started, check if you can still use your phpmyadmin. If you can still use it then nothing is wrong with your database server.
- wrong config; check username, password and server settings in both your .env file and your config/database.php
- no privileges to the server and or database with given credentials
  Looking at the steps you already took I think it's the last.

Check to see if this user has access to the database from the remote location. By default the root user has access to the server locally (localhost,127.0.0.1 and ::1).

So check to see if the user has access from either your remote ip or from anywhere.

As you are using digitalocean I would suggest to check if they have a specific configuration to connect to mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

SELinux might be the cause.

Set this rule and try again:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

Answer (score 1):

After long hours this worked for me:

Changing the port in php My Admin previously 8889

```
APP_NAME=laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY= YOUR KEY
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=127.0.0.1

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and then

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you do changes as per instructed above,

1. check if your database server running or not. If you are using `command prompt`, running `mysql.server` status or `mysqld` status shall show the database status.
2. If the database is running, check if the `dbuser` is allow to connect from `'%'` or `'localhost'` or `'127.0.0.1'`. If not, just grant the user access from `'%'`
3. If you have done 1 and 2 and still can't connect, see if the db user is allow to access the schema. If not, grant access to the schema
4. If you reach here and still got the same error, try to restart you web server.

Answer (score -1):

My composer was installed globally, i run php artisan serve without starting xampp & getting this error. After running my xampp server, it's working fine from my side.

Answer (score -1):

In attempt to provide a solution for those of you that have not found success in any of the already mentioned answers, I will share my solution.

Coming from Windows 10 I was of the understanding that the password for the root user was always blank thus my .env file looked as follows:

```
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

On Mac, the password is defaulted to "root" also. Changing my .env file to look as follows fixed my issue:

```
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Answer (score -1):

in your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ur_db_name
DB_USERNAME=ur_db_username
DB_PASSWORD=ur_dbuser_password
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using XAMPP on Mac, just use the embedded IP Address from your XAMPP Dashboard as `DB_HOST` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

If It still refuses to connect deal with a user but stick on that idea.