# Laravel Homestead-authentication not working

Tags: laravel, homestead

I've setup Homestead and the site is up and running. It connects to my database and migrates tables.
The problem is that when I create a new project with authentication using this command : ***laravel new blog --auth***, when I go to the register page and want to register a user I get this error:***Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = vlad@yahoo.com)***. The user is not inserted into the database and cannot go further.

Comment: did you migrate tables succesfully?

Comment: Yes. The migrations are working. Found out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41247114/11003430 and I've changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost and now it works. Don't know why though....

Answer (score 0):

Found out this post: stackoverflow.com/a/41247114/11003430 and I've changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost and now it works. Don't know why though