# Problem while runnning php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = pracatice and table_name = migrations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225720/laravel-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

1. First check the `composer require doctrine/dbal` is installed
   if this composer is not installed then install it
2. Check the database port number is correct or not with other information like
   `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1,DB_PORT=3307,DB_DATABASE=pracatice,DB_USERNAME=root,DB_PASSWORD=`
3. Check the files permission for project this is also most important for running `php artisan migrate`
4. Then retry `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

In the .env file, try to change your DB_HOST from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: This won't help, localhost and 127.0.0.1 is the same thing.

Comment: Okay, please look at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead)

Comment: It is a specific case for MAC OS