Connection refused Laravel 11 deployed on Infinityfree.com
I have deployed a Laravel 11 app on infinity free and I get this error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from sessionswhereid = 84HY52h5ZEh8bPRRtkAgdSRZygnZ41PCngEZ4AI6 limit 1)

I imported database from my local phpmyadmin.
My database is correctly configured and my .env file has all the correct data for database so I don't know what is the problem.
This is free shared hosting and I don't have terminal on there so if any of you have any solutions that can be done with php script, that would be good.
In htdocs folder there are: answerfinder (folder containing all the folders and filex except public) and files from public folder including .htaccess and index.php. I changed directory in index.php file so that it goes to answerfinder folder and that part is good.
Also I have run these commands before deploying:
php artisan optimize
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan event:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
npm run build

Everything works perfectly fine locally.
I haven't made any changes to .htaccess file.

Have you configured config/database.php?

I haven't changed anything in database.php file, it's default. I tried manually typing host,database name etc. but it's the same.

In .env is your DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1?

This link might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225720/laravel-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

My db host is host provided by infinityfree, but i tried changing it back to 127.0.0.1 but no changes
